# Random walk through Ising model

Tags: ising-model, stochastic-processes, randomness

Ising model consists of up spin and down spin or empty/filled space. Can we model random walk for different densities of packing through the Ising model?

Comment: What do you mean by "Can we model random walk for different densities of packing through ising model"?

Comment: Hello Yvan , i am working on tipping points (phase transition) in ecological systems such as lake system using ising model. Here i am focusing on flow dynamics through vegetation .I want to simulate particle velocity using ising model  for different packing of spins (vegetation ) .Hope , i made it clear

Answer (score -1):

There are ways to map the magnetization distribution problem of the Ising model to persistent random walks. The relevant references are:

R. Garcia-Pelayo, "Distribution of magnetization in the finite Ising chain," Journal of Mathematical Physics 50, 013301 (2009)

and

T. Antal, M. Droz, and Z. Racz, "Probability distribution of magnetization in the one-dimensional Ising model: effects of boundary conditions,"  Journal of  Physics A: Mathematics and General 37, 1465 (2004)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can imagine going through 1D Ising model as random walk, analogous to [Maximal Entropy Random Walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_entropy_random_walk), e.g. to model 2D Ising $w\times \infty$ as 1D for width $w$ slices ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.13300 ).

For $M_{ij}=\exp(-\beta E_{ij})$ transfer matrix, where  $E_{ij}$ is energy of $i-j$ edge (e.g. negative for the same spins in ferromagnet), you need to find dominant eigenvector $M\psi = \lambda \psi$, then

stationary probability distribution is $Pr(i)\propto (\psi_i)^2$,

Stochastic matrix: $S_{ij}=Pr(x_t=j|x_{t-1}=i)= \frac{M_{ij}}{\lambda} \frac{\psi_j}{\psi_i}$.

Sketch of derivation:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/CW3Lvrk.png]